# How to show spinner in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, spinner

I am new to angular and web development but able to design various web pages and got data from the server using HTTP client module.

While getting data from server I want to show progress spinner, but I am not able to do it. I have searched google but nothing made me to do it. Please help me to achieve this.

Code:

login.component.ts

```
 userLogin() {
        console.log('logging in');
        this.eService.signIn(this.user_name, this.password)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log(data);
               this.admin = data;
               if ( this.admin.firstLogin === true) {
                   // go to update admin password
               } else {
                this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                }
               localStorage.setItem('isLoggedin', 'true');
             }
        );
    }
```

login.html

```
<div class="login-page" [@routerTransition]>
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="150px" class="user-avatar" />
            <h1>Users/h1>
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-content">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="user_name" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="" placeholder="username">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" (keyup.enter)="userLogin()" class="form-control input-underline input-lg" id="" placeholder="password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="btn rounded-btn" (click)="userLogin()"> Log in </a>
                &nbsp;
                <a class="btn rounded-btn" >Clear</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when I am requesting signIn service I want to show the spinner, Please help me, how can I do it?

I know this is simple for many of the developers here, but for me It is getting somewhat tough.

Answer (score 12):

Add the spinner into your HTML code, like so:

```
<img *ngIf="loading" src="assets/my-spinner.gif" /> <!-- Or use a CSS one if you like -->
```

Then, in your Typescript, you need to create a variable called `loading`, and set it like so:

```
userLogin() {
    console.log('logging in');
    this.loading = true; // Add this line
    this.eService.signIn(this.user_name, this.password)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log(data);
           this.loading = false; // And this one
           this.admin = data;
           if ( this.admin.firstLogin === true) {
               // go to update admin password
           } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
            }
           localStorage.setItem('isLoggedin', 'true');
         }
    );
}
```

This will set `loading` to true while the service is in action

Comment: If I add like this, again I have to consider the placement of the gif right?

Comment: What is it you want to acheive? You can place it using CSS

Comment: I want show over the current opened page..just like overlay

Comment: Yeah, use CSS. Here is a basic example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbyatu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css Just click the button to see the spinner

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`ng4-loading-spinner`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng4-loading-spinner)

Execute `npm i ng4-loading-spinner --save`

Import module to your application root module

```
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
```

Make an import entry

```
 imports: [ Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot() ]
```

Include spinner component to your root level component.

```
<ng4-loading-spinner> </ng4-loading-spinner>
```

use `show()` and `hide()` inside `subscribe` callback

```
import { Ng4LoadingSpinnerService } from 'ng4-loading-spinner';
 constructor(
        private spinnerService: Ng4LoadingSpinnerService
    ) { }
    userLogin() {

        this.spinnerService.show();
            console.log('logging in');
            this.eService.signIn(this.user_name, this.password)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log(data);
                   this.admin = data;
                   if ( this.admin.firstLogin === true) {
                       // go to update admin password
                   } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                    }
                   localStorage.setItem('isLoggedin', 'true');
                 },
               ()=>this.spinnerService.hide();
            );
        }
```

**[`Live Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng4-loading-spinner)**

Comment: Hi @Vikas I used this one but when I'm trying to import in my app.module I'm getting `Error: "Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:[..]/ng4-loading-spinner
  Loading http://localhost:[..]/client/app/app.module.js
  Loading client/main.js"` I use Angular 5 which should be supported according to the doc

Answer (score 1):

For those who still search for loading spinner in angular, please feel free to look at:

- if you need only initial loading just have a look: [How To Style Angular Application Loading With Angular CLI Like a
  Boss](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/how-to-style-angular-application-loading-with-angular-cli-like-a-boss-cdd4f5358554)  by Tomas.
- if you would like to check all the four ways of loading spinner here you go:

  [The Four ways to Create Loading Spinners in an Angular App](https://christianlydemann.com/four-ways-to-create-loading-spinners-in-an-angular-app/) by Cristian.

Answer (score 0):

Add this HTML code

```html
<div class="spinner-border" role="status" *ngIf="your_condition">
      <span class="sr-only" id="loadbar"></span>
</div>
```

in .css file (add necessary styling),

```css
#loadbar{
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  }

@keyframes spin {
0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

set the condition to true or false as per your code in .ts file
```