# Show and hide Spinner when a file upload/downloads

Tags: angular

I need to show spinner when a client clicks to download a file while waiting for the blob to display. But now, when ngif is set to !show the spinner keeps loading and never stops. In the other way round, if ngif is set as shown  no spinner in the background while the blob is shown.

```html
<app-spinner *ngIf="show"></app-spinner>
    <a *ngIf="editing && !show" title="Download Book" id="downloadLink" (click)="downloadBook(myBook.id, myBook.attachedName)"> 
        {{nameAttached}}
    </a>
</app-spinner>
```

I set a variable show: boolean; in the typescript.

Download method

```
// method to download Book
downloadBook(id: number, attachedName: string) {
    this.downloadBookService.downloadBook(id, attachedName);
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you setting the `show` variable and updating it to `true` or `false`? Can you show that code please?

Comment: downloadBook does not seem to update show based on activity start or end.
Here is link to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000252/how-to-show-spinner-in-angular-6

Answer (score 2):

Dependending on whether or not the downloadBook() is observable:

```
// method to download Book
downloadBook(id: number, attachedName: string) {
    this.show = true;
    this.downloadBookService.downloadBook(id, attachedName);
    this.show = false;
}
```

If it is a subscription, then always set `this.show = false` in the subscription finalize statement (so that it will stop spinning even on error).

```
// method to download Book
downloadBook(id: number, attachedName: string) {
    this.show = true;
    this.downloadBookService.downloadBook(id, attachedName)
        .pipe(
            finalize(() => this.show = false) // Execute when the observable completes
        );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set value of show to false once the blob content is received.

```
downloadBook(id: number, attachedName: string) {  
    this.downloadBookService.downloadBook(id, attachedName); 
    this.show = false;
}
```

Ideally if downloadBookService.downloadBook is an asynchronous then u should be using callback function to update the show flag.

Something like below:

```
downloadBook(id: number, attachedName: string) {  
    this.downloadBookService.downloadBook(id, attachedName)
        .subscribe (resp => {
            show =false;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add an Injectable Service

```
@Injectable()
```

export class SpinnerHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

```
constructor(private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

   if(req.url.endsWith('your/url')) {
       this.spinner.show();
   }
       return next.handle(req).pipe(finalize(() => {

           /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
           this.spinner.hide();

       }));


}
```

}